# Use additional JNDI with Spring Boot

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, datasource, jndi

I have an enterprise application set to work with a JNDI. Here's the configuration in my `application.properties`.

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/MYPRIMARYDATABASE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=jta
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.transaction.factory_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=NON_NULL
```

and my Spring main: `Application.java`

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "it.mypackage.data.access.database" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "it.mypackage.data.access.model" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "it.mypackage" })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {

        return emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }

}
```

Inside the package `it.mypackage.data.access.database` there is a DAO interface and a DAO facade which perform operations on the datasource and in the `it.mypackage.data.access.model` package where all table entities are declared.

**DatabaseDAOFacade.java**

```java
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DatabaseDAOFacade implements DatabaseDAOInterface {

    private final SessionFactory sf;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    protected Session getSession() {

        return sf.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseDAOFacade(SessionFactory sf, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.sf = sf;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T save(T o) {

        return (T) this.getSession().save(o);
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Here I have a new *entity* which should use an **additional JNDI**

**Photo.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PHOTO")
public class Photo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "PHOTO_REQUEST_SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PHOTO_REQUEST_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "PHOTO_REQUESTS")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USERID")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "UPLOAD_DATE")
    private Date uploadDate;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Is there a clean way to add a second JNDI and set `Photo.java` to use the new one?

Comment: From a second JNDI you mean that you need to use more than 1 datasource, right? If yes [check this example from spring-projects](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources)
It is a little tricky and you need to follow strict package organization.

Comment: yep a new datasource. Checkin' your link right away

Comment: unfortunately we tried that approach without success